# Pycharm adding new project interpreter makes duplicate

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm, whenever I try to add new Project Interpreters, two duplicated entries are created.

For example, after adding 2.7.10 python.exe, interpreter list contains two elements:

- 2.7.10 (C:\Python27\python.exe)
- 2.7.10 (C:\Python27\python.exe)(1)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be some kind of bug in PyCharm.

As a workaround, you may remove duplicated entries manually. They are located in config file in PyCharm preferences directory. Default path is `~/.PyCharmxy/config/options/jdk.table.xml`, where xy represents version (e.g. `PyCharm40` for PyCharm 4.x).

Each `<jdk>` element represents single configured interpreter. To remove duplicates simply find elements with subelement `<name value="your duplicate name"`> and delete entire `<jdk>` tag.

Sample entry looks like below. (1) in name indicates duplicate.

```
<jdk version="2">
  <name value="Python 2.7.10 (C:\Python27\python.exe) (1)" />
  <type value="Python SDK" />
  <version value="Python 2.7.10" />
  <homePath value="C:\Python27\python.exe" />
  (...) // a lot of other fields
</jdk>
```

Answer is based on [The mystery of PyCharm and duplicate interpreters](http://www.sonictk.com/the-mystery-of-pycharm-and-duplicate-interpreters/) blog post.