# requests.get function causes TypeError when it should not

Tags: python-requests

I am beginner and I wanted to learn how to work with Python requests library. I watched some tutorials and I wanted to try it out but I immediately ran into TypeError with note: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Althought I am completely sure that I use only one argument because the  code looks as following:

```
   import requests
    r = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com')

I appreciate every advice

full Error output is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Test.4.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com')
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 315, in get_connection
    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_url(url)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 298, in connection_from_url
    return self.connection_from_host(
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 245, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 260, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 281, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 213, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
  File "C:\Users\filip\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.pool = self.QueueCls(maxsize)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: I just ran your code, and it does execute correctly. The `r` in your snippet is a `<Response [200]>` that indicates the request has succedded.

Comment: Does your entire file, consist only of these 2 lines? Are you using a virtual environment? How are you executing the script? Can you add more details?

Comment: Yes, it is the entire code and and I use Pycharm as IDE.

Comment: To help you we need: (a) the full code, (b) the full error-output, (c) the module and version where `init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @FilipSmitka - I can guarantee you that's not the full code, that is getting executed. - "if" you are getting the error. Can you run the code on your terminal - outside of Pycharm?

Comment: Okay, I see what is happening. It's related to your virtual environment that Pycharm has created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please clean your workspace (or) virtual environments by looking into this [Pycharm & Virtualenvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979145/pycharm-virtualenvs-how-to-remove-legacy#:%7E:text=You%20can%20clean%20out%20old,PyCharm%20thinks%20are%20still%20around.). This will help in cleaning your workspace, and resolving issues you are currently encountering.
2. I have tested your code snippet.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com')
print(r)
```

Sample O/P:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Here the `<Response [200]>` response indicates that the request has succeeded.